# Launching windows 10 store apps

Tags: c#, windows-10

I am looking for a way to launch/run windows store apps on windows 10/8.1 from C#.

Examples of the apps I am trying to run are

1. Calculator
2. Photos
3. Settings

Note: in Windows 10 these are no longer standard .exe files that can be executed by double clicking or calling Process.Start() as they are now windows store apps.

I have tried to use IApplicationActivationManager but I cannot find decent documentation with examples of how to use it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, just a regular console app.

Answer (score 11):

I found a cool way to run every Windows Universal apps which downloaded via Windows Store or preinstalled.
Each Windows 10 Universal app has an `AUMID` which stands for 'Application User Model ID'.

**PowerShell** Command to get all AUMID:

```
get-StartApps
```

Output:

> ```
> PS C:\> get-StartApps
>
> Name                      AppID
> ----                      -----
> Skype                     Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
> Snip & Sketch             Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Mail                      microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Calendar                  microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Movies & TV               Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneVideo
> OneNote for Windows 10    Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.onenoteim
> Photos                    Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Video Editor              Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!SecondaryEntry
> Maps                      Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Alarms & Clock            Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Voice Recorder            Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Feedback Hub              Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Xbox Game Bar             Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Camera                    Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Microsoft Store           Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Weather                   Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Cortana                   Microsoft.549981C3F5F10_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Instagram                 Facebook.InstagramBeta_8xx8rvfyw5nnt!Instagram
> ...
> ```

So now, you can start any universal app via its AUMID like this:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\[AUMID]
```

For example, if you want to execute `Skype`:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
```

Now it's the time to back to Csharp:

```
Process.Start("explorer shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
```

The `Windows Weather` App will execute.

Comment: This is a great solution. Following the other registry based one is tedious, and my Microsoft Store WSL Ubuntu installation wasn't even there.  

It was listed by your PS get command, and using your explorer template with the relevant name works perfectly from command line and `Process.Start()`.

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways to do it. The easiest way is to use `Process.Start` and the URL or file handlers.

For example this will open the Video app:

```
Process.Start("microsoftvideo://");
```

Or the Store on the updates page:

```
Process.Start("ms-windows-store:updates");
```

Or the Photos app:

```
Process.Start("ms-photos://");
```

There are several more handles, some of them can you find [here](http://www.itsjustwhatever.com/2012/10/28/launch-windows-8-metro-apps-from-a-desktop-shortcut-or-command-line/). You can find the names when you open the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId`. Look for the `CustomProperties` key. It has an attribute `Name`. That is the one to use.

Some other useful pointer can be found on SU: [How do I run a Metro-Application from the command-line in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/q/433477/302087).

Comment: @Tom: was this post helpful to you? Need more help?

Comment: Its helpful, and it definitely works, the only problem is I don't know the URL for all apps for example Calculator or Calendar, also what about non standard apps installed form the app store.

Comment: Me neither. You have to go to the registry yourself to see for yourself.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm trying to use `Process.Start()` but I get a compiler error. It doesn't find the library or whatever but that doesn't make much sense since this library is included in .NET 4.6. Do you have any idea about what it's happening?

Comment: @EvaFP Please create a new question, link to this question/answer and please link to me here. I have to know more about your project type and current code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman here's the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268249/system-diagnostics-process-not-working-in-windows-10. I don't know if you need further information... Thx!!

Comment: @PatrickHofman The link to itsjustwhatever is dead (the site is gone). Do you have an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer another option. If you run in Powershell the following command:

```
(New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}").Items() | sort Name | ft Name,Path
```

or

```
get-StartApps | sort Name
```

You get pretty much the same output. However, the 1st command is a bit more useful. It has a clear delimiter - the colon **:** , whereas the 2nd command (the one marked as the answer) does not.
Might be useful in certain situations where you need to separate the **PackageFamilyName** from the **App_ID** using the split() command.

Comment: The question was how to do it in C#