# Launching a Windows 10 Store app from C# executable

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

So here's the gist of my problem: I have a keyboard where I can assign macros and/or launch programs from. I want to include a couple Win10 and Steam applications in that list. So I opted to build an executable "launcher", so to speak.

The code is simplistic in nature. I got Steam url's to work by placing the steam url into Process.Start("steam://rungameid/#####"). I cannot, however, figure out how to get Win10 apps to work. Here's my class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!Netflix.App");
        Process.Start(@"shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!Netflix.App");
        Process.Start("netflix://");

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Each line of Process.Start() is what I've tried, to no avail.

The bottom line I attempted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075310/1821925), which also did not work

The first line, I can put that in a Run box or from the command line saDand it will launch Netflix, but from the C# application, I get a "System cannot find the file" exception.

Thanks for any direction!

Comment: Yeah that link will only work for _well-known_ /protocol apps I suspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check if you have installed this app and name you enter in the Process.Start(“ ”) is correct, You can find the names when you open the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId. Look for the CustomProperties key. It has an attribute Name. I use the below sample to open my photos, It works fine.

```
 private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2_Click(null,null);
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("ms-photos://");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure... BUT, here's the thing - in my Form1_Load(), it will not trigger Process.Start("netflix://"); (nor will it trigger Process.Start("ms-photos://")). If I place a button on the form, with Process.Start("netflix://"); in the button1_click() method, with button1_click(null,null); in Form1_Load(), it will not work BUT does work when manually clicking the button. Creating a new method private void LaunchNetflix(){ Process.Start("netflix://"); } with LaunchNetflix(); in Form1_Load() does not trigger it automatically as well.

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem... It's Visual Studio Community 2017 RC. The same code I posted in the question, `Process.Start("netflix:\\");`, when built with Visual Studio 2015 Community works flawlessly. I will have to submit feedback to the VS team on this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jparnell8839,Glad to hear that you have solved your problem by yourself, Thanks for sharing your result.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```cs
Process.Start(
    @"explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!Netflix.App"
);
```

Do this

```cs
Process.Start(
    "explorer.exe",
    "shell:AppsFolder\4DF9E0F8.Netflix_mcm4njqhnhss8!Netflix.App"
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem.  Currently unable to launch a windows app store application from c#.  I used a work around for now.  I made a bat file that navigates to the desktop and launches the desktop shortcut link.  Then I call my bat file which launches the app store application.

Example of BAT file:

```
   cd\
   cd Users\d1\OneDrive\Desktop
   "XYZ Games - Shortcut.lnk"
```

Example Code C#:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "launcherXYZGames.bat";
proc.Start();
```