# How to get notified for closing an application invoked via Process?

Tags: c#

I want to get notified when the calculator is closed. The following code does not work; the `Exited` appears even though I have not closed the calculator. What modification do I have to write?

```
static void Main()
{
    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Exited += (x, y) => Console.WriteLine("Exited");
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this has to do with "calc.exe" or may be if it is because you already have it running. Are you getting the same result when running "notepad.exe" ?

Comment: @AnuViswan: Yes the same when using notepad.

Comment: interesting, for me it worked for notepad, while didnt for calc.exe

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity what Windows version you are using? 10 and calculator is UWP app?

Comment: @AnuViswan +1 same on my Win10 x64 Pro

Comment: @woldemar: I am using  Windows 10 Enterprise Trial. I am debugging with Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Winsows 10, calculator is UWP app there and should be started with *app url* typically:
[Launching a Windows 10 Store app from C# executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521332/launching-a-windows-10-store-app-from-c-sharp-executable)

I bet Microsoft coders created kludge to allow run UWP calculator by same way as in previous Windows versions to keep backward compatibility, so, very probably, some *proxy* process(es) runs UWP calculator and ends immediately, so you have unexpected behaviour.

Also `p.WaitForExit()` is used as *sync*, and `p.Exited` as *async* way to wait process ending and usually they are not used together, you should choose one.

Comment: The same issue with `mspaint.ext`, is it UWP?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity `mspaint.exe` works as expected for me, but `Exited` event was fired 2 times... It was not a UWP app initially as we know, but you also can read this: https://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-bringing-ms-paint-windows-store-free
We can only guess through that mincer `mspaint` gone to be migrated to store... It may be legacy app in UWP container for example lol... I can't explain Microsoft magic, but think something unfathomable happens there :)