# Microsoft To Do - How do I hard Code using path

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

**WHAT I NEED:**

I am trying to use a button to open MS To Do directly from inside my solution. But, neither the MS To Do exec file nor the path work? Does anyone know whether the exec file is in another location? I would greatly appreciate any help! I have googled everything I can think of to find a solution and nothing seems to work?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

1. WINDOWS APPS FOLDER: Microsoft To Do app is apparently in this folder which is inaccessible. But, the following procedure provides access to this folder by changing ownership:

PROJECT: HOW TO ACCESS THE WINDOWSAPPS FOLDER.

SOURCE: [https://www.alphr.com/access-windows-apps-folder/#:~:text=Windows%2010%20Apps%20folder%20is,C%3A%2FProgram%20Files%2FWindowsApps](https://www.alphr.com/access-windows-apps-folder/#:%7E:text=Windows%2010%20Apps%20folder%20is,C%3A%2FProgram%20Files%2FWindowsApps).

2. MICROSOFT TO DO FOLDER: There are 4 folders with similar names in the Windows Apps folder. The one we're interested in is the 4th folder (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.74.51921.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe). At the bottom of the list of files in this folder there is the Microsoft To Do exec file (i.e. Application). However, double clicking this file doesn't open the app. Rather, two notifications (i.e. message boxes) are shown:

   "The code execution cannot proceed because SharedLibrary.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

   "The code execution cannot proceed because mrt100_app was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

I have already reinstalled the program but this didn't fix the problem?

3. MICROSOFT TO DO PATH: Tried hard coding the path from the properties of the app as follows, but the same problem occurs?

Right click the exec file > Properties > Security Tab > Advanced button > Path is at top of Advanced Properties as follows:

MICROSOFT TO DO PATH: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.74.51921.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Todo.exe

4. I also tried creating a desktop shortcut from the exec file, but it doesn't work and it doesn't create the MS To Do icon as a shortcut. That's why I wonder if this is the real exec file?

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

[How To Get Modern Apps Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901747/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-icons-for-win10-ms-store-apps/73968585#73968585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining some answers from [Launching windows 10 store apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074404/launching-windows-10-store-apps):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Todos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App")
```

(Tested with VS2022 on W11.)