# How do I programmatically get the icons for WIN10 / MS Store Apps?

Tags: windows, vb.net, icons

[image: ListView Using My.Resources]

I have been googling forever for a way to programmatically get the **icons**  for WIN10 / MS Apps (i.e. Modern Apps)? I already have the AUMIDs (e.g. `7-ZIP FILE MANAGER;shell:appsfolder\{6D809377-6AF0-444B-8957-A3773F02200E}\7-Zip\7zFM.exe`) working in my program and also the shell commands (e.g. `Apps Folder;shell:AppsFolder`). I also have access to the Applications folder, but I can't find a way to get the MS App / Windows Store icons to display on my Preview button? Do you have any ideas? I am using Visual Studio 2019 / VB.NET. My program uses a ListView to display each of the programs/apps/folders and currently extracts icons from executable paths to display on dynamically created buttons and also on a Preview button which can be clicked to run the app/program. But, I can't find a way to do the same thing for WIN10/MS Store Apps? If anyone has any ideas or can even show some code which extracts these icons directly from the system I would greatly appreciate it! I'm sorry I don't have any code to show because I have been looking for many days and can't find any examples!

**What I need**

In the Applications folder (i.e. virtual), you can create Desktop icons from the MS Apps Icons as follows. But, if the program I'm trying to create depends upon these Desktop shortcuts this seems to be very limited. I really need to find a way to access the native MS Apps icons to display when running each app from my program.

**MS Apps Desktop Icons**

[image]

**LIST OF MS APPS WITHOUT ICONS**

By "without icons" I mean that I haven't found a way yet to get or extract these icons from the system? The idea of the icons is to visually identify the program or app currently selected in the ListView items on the preview button and also on dynamically created buttons which run the program/app!

MS APPS:

```
BING WEATHER;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
CALENDAR;"shell:appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.calendar";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
CORTANA;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.549981C3F5F10_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MAIL;"shell:appsfolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MICROSOFTSOLITAIRECOLLECTION;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS 3D VIEWER;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS MAPS;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS ONE NOTE;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.onenoteim";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS TO DO;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Todos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS WORD ONLINE VERSION???;"shell:appsfolder\word.office.com-CECA1A7F_jc2kecmnkxwqc!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
PAINT 3D;shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.MSPaint_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.MSPaint;Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
PHOTOSHOP EXPRESS;"shell:appsfolder\AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress_mtcwf2zmmt10c!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
WINDOWS CLOCK;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
WINDOWS PHOTOS;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
WINDOWS SOUND RECORDER;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
ZUNE MUSIC;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneMusic";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
ZUNE VIDEO;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneVideo";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
```

OTHERS:

```
INTELGRAPHICSEXPERIENCE;"shell:appsfolder\AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience_8j3eq9eme6ctt!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS GET HELP;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.GetHelp_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
MS GET STARTED TIPS;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.Getstarted_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
WINDOWS FEEDBACK HUB;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
WINDOWS MIXED REALITY PORTAL;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
YOUR PHONE;"shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";Winver___LocalLang_2_MAINICON
```

**My Research**

I tried Nirsoft's utility program, IconsExtract [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html). This utility works even on system folders without throwing an exception! I first tried individual folders and then C drive (with subfolders) in an attempt to find the WIN10 Apps icons. I found many icons that I was looking for, but the MS Apps Icons I found all turned out to be cursors? They appear as the MS Apps Icons, but when you copy them the app icon image changes to a cursor? I also previously tried Icon Extractor [IconExtractor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6672/Icon-Extractor-in-VB-NET) which is a great little program with the plus that you can see the code behind. However, I found Nirsoft's utility to extract high quality icons without throwing exceptions on system folders or even dll files!

**Related Questions**

[how-can-i-use-a-resource-string-as-a-listview-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73929357/how-can-i-use-a-resource-string-as-a-listview-item)

**Further Resources (URLs)**

[launching-windows-10-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074404/launching-windows-10-store-apps)

[find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app)

[launching-windows-10-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074404/launching-windows-10-store-apps)

[shell-commands-for-windows-10-navigating-common-folders-in-windows](https://www.mirazon.com/shell-commands-for-windows-10-navigating-common-folders-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Game Fire app showing apps imported from Microsoft Store]

I use the **PackageManager** class part of **Windows.Management.Deployment** namespace to retrieve information about the installed Microsoft Store apps including their icons.

To use the [PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager?view=winrt-22621) class add reference to **Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract** located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References[SDK Version]\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract[Version]\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd**

Use the following code to enumerate the installed packages and apps:

```
Imports Windows.Management.Deployment

Module Test

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim pkgMngr As New PackageManager()

        For Each package In pkgMngr.FindPackages()

            Try

                For Each app In package.GetAppListEntries

                    Try

                        Dim pkgVersion = package.Id.Version

                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("App name: {0}", app.DisplayInfo.DisplayName))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Package logo file: {0}", package.Logo.OriginalString))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Package publisher: {0}", package.PublisherDisplayName))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("AppUserModelId: {0}", app.AppUserModelId))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("App description: {0}", app.DisplayInfo.Description))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Install location: {0}", package.InstalledPath))
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Package version: {0}", New Version(pkgVersion.Major, pkgVersion.Minor, pkgVersion.Build, pkgVersion.Revision).ToString))

                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                        Console.ResetColor()

                    Finally
                        Console.WriteLine(New String("-"c, 10))

                    End Try

                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                Console.ResetColor()
            End Try

        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

The **Package.Logo** property will give you the package logo file path, usually a PNG image file. You can load the image easily using the **Image.FromFile** method.

Here is an extra method to help get the app cover art/wide logo by parsing the app manifest file **AppxManifest.xml**, just specify the app install path to the **GetStoreAppCoverArt** method.

The screenshot is for our app Game Fire displaying apps/games imported from Microsoft Store using their cover/wide logos.

```
Private Function GetStoreAppCoverArt(appInstallDir As String) As String

    Try

        Dim manifestFilePath = Path.Combine(appInstallDir, "AppxManifest.xml")

        If File.Exists(manifestFilePath) Then

            Dim xmlDocAppManifest As XmlDocument = Nothing

            If IsValidXml(manifestFilePath, xmlDocAppManifest) Then

                Dim defaultTitleNode As XmlNode = xmlDocAppManifest.DocumentElement.Item("Applications").Item("Application").Item("uap:VisualElements").Item("uap:DefaultTile")

                If defaultTitleNode IsNot Nothing Then

                    Dim wideLogoValue = defaultTitleNode.Attributes("Wide310x150Logo").Value.Trim

                    Dim logoFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wideLogoValue)
                    Dim assetsDir = Path.Combine(appInstallDir, Path.GetDirectoryName(wideLogoValue))

                    For Each f In New DirectoryInfo(assetsDir).EnumerateFiles("*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

                        If f.Name.StartsWith(logoFileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                            Return f.FullName
                        End If

                    Next

                Else
                    Throw New XmlException("Application uap:DefaultTile node is missing.")
                End If

            Else
                Throw New XmlException("Application manifest file is invalid.")
            End If

        End If

        Return String.Empty

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try

End Function

Public Function IsValidXml(filePath As String, ByRef xDoc As XmlDocument) As Boolean

    Try

        If File.Exists(filePath) Then

            Dim errInfo As Exception = Nothing

            Using fs = CreateFileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, errInfo)

                If fs Is Nothing Then Throw errInfo

                Using sr = New StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, True)
                    Using xReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, New XmlReaderSettings() With {.XmlResolver = Nothing})
                        xDoc = New XmlDocument() With {.XmlResolver = Nothing}
                        xDoc.Load(xReader)
                        Return True
                    End Using
                End Using

            End Using

            Return False

        Else
            Throw New FileNotFoundException("The specifed file does not exit.", filePath)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Public Function CreateFileStream(filePah As String, mode As FileMode, access As FileAccess, share As FileShare, Optional ByRef errInfo As Exception = Nothing, Optional retries As Integer = 10) As FileStream

    For i = 0 To retries - 1

        Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing

        Try

            fs = New FileStream(filePah, mode, access, share)
            errInfo = Nothing
            Return fs

        Catch ex As IOException
            errInfo = ex
            If fs IsNot Nothing Then fs.Dispose()
            Thread.Sleep(100)

        Catch ex As Exception
            errInfo = ex
            Return Nothing

        End Try

    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed. Thanks for your help! I'm not a gamer! I just looked at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata[Version], but I don't have UnionMetadata just Catalog? I'm really searching for a way to get the icons for the WIN10 Apps that come with Windows, i.e. MS Apps Desktop Icons section. It would be great to also include MS Store Apps icons as well. I'm not sure how I can try what you suggest because I don't have the UnionMetadata part of the path you mention?

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson 
To use the PackageManager class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager?view=winrt-22621 add references to Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References[SDK Version]\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract[Version]\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd . The app icons will be similar to this https://ibb.co/B6PvVhV

Comment: Hi @Ahmed. Sorry, I just saw your post! I have tried adding a reference as you suggest, but still can't find anything in the folder except the Catalog folder? I posted a screenshot of browsing to the path you mention as I attempted to add a reference? Not sure if there's something missing on my PC or if I need to add something? I know that Game Bar for XBOX isn't recording? I used to use it, but it stopped working? Don't know if that has anything to do with it? Tried reinstalling, but still doesn't work?

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson Then you will need to install the Windows SDK [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)

Comment: Hi @ahmed. I installed the SDK and created a reference in VS 2019. Placed the code you supplied for Package Manager behind a button in my program. But, on the Code Line: For Each package In pkgMngr.FindPackages(), I get the following exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied? I'm a little confused as to how to get the app icons as you mention in your comment (ibb.co/B6PvVhV)? I also downloaded Game Fire because you posted a screenshot, but I don't know how to get the icons there either? Can you explain a little more? I really want to get there, but don't know how?

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson From Microsoft: _This method requires administrative privileges. Otherwise, an AccessDeniedException is thrown._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages?view=winrt-22621#windows-management-deployment-packagemanager-findpackages . To run your app with administrative privileges, set the **level** attribute of the **requestedExecutionLevel** node in the **app.manifest** file to **requireAdministrator**

 BTW the Game Fire screenshot I posted belongs to unreleased software version.

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, I tried that, and it worked just fine! I got the icon paths and install location paths! I spent a long time today setting up to use the new info. Greatly appreciate all your help on that!