# How Can I Use A Resource String As a ListView Item

Tags: vb.net, listview, bitmap, windows-10, resources

[image: Use Resource String As ListView Item]

**What I Am Working On**

1. **My.Resources:** I have a lot of icons in My.Resources that I want to display on a "preview button" (i.e. Button10 in the code snippet). So, I added the resource strings (See screenshot) as text to my ListView (i.e. Column1 = Program Name; Column2 = Path; Column3 = My.Resources) alongside their respective programs which is necessary to synch the images. The reason I'm attempting to achieve this is for programs which don't have file paths to extract the program icons from, i.e. WIN10 MS Apps and MS Store Apps which use Application User Model ID (AUMID). Unless anyone knows how to access/extract the WIN10 MS Apps and MS Store Apps icons from the system?
2. **Problem:** I'm trying to find a way to "cast" the resource from the resource string in the ListView column to a bitmap to use as the image on the preview button (i.e. SelectedIndexChanged). I'm not sure if casting is the right way to go?
3. **What I have tried:** The closest I have managed to get is the following code which
   throws an exception (i.e. System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.')? The Text being passed appears to be correct.

[[VB.NET] Convert a string to an image](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f621f40-dc3d-48aa-831f-bc4041f64451/vbnet-convert-a-string-to-an-image?forum=vbgeneral)

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ListView4.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(2).Text.ToString)
        Button10.Image = CType(bmp, System.Drawing.Bitmap)
```

**4. jmcilhinney's solution**

[image: Using Resources in ListView]

```
Dim resourceName = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text.ToString
        Dim icon = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName), Icon)
        Dim bmp = icon.ToBitmap()

        Button10.BackgroundImage = bmp
        Button10.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

**Related Questions**

[how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-icons-for-win10-ms-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901747/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-icons-for-win10-ms-store-apps)

**Resources (URLs)**

[launching-windows-10-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074404/launching-windows-10-store-apps)

[find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/find-the-application-user-model-id-of-an-installed-app)

Comment: That you have controls named `ListView4` and `Button10` is a bad sign. You should be naming everything sensibly and descriptively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListView` appears to contain code snippets that you expect to execute at run time. That's not how it works. You can't just execute a `string` as though it were compiled code. If you want to get a resource from `My.Resources` based on its name as a `string` then you can do this:

```vb
Dim resourceObject = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName), ResourceType)
```

In your case, you would need to store the actual names, e.g. "Bridge_0" and "Photoshop_1000", and use those values. You'll need to cast as type `Icon` and then call `ToBitmap` yourself, e.g.

```vb
Dim resourceName = ListView4.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2)
Dim icon = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName), Icon)
Dim bmp = icon.ToBitmap()
```

Comment: Hey thanks @jmcilhinney. Appreciate you help on that! I'm going to start working on that and I'll let you know how I get along. I went with the above option based on the fact that I'm already using the executable paths in column 2 both to extract icons and run the respective programs. I thought maybe I could use resources in the same way, but obviously it doesn't work :-)!

Comment: thanks mate that code just plain works! Brilliant! :-) I'm currently using icons in resources which I got using Nirsoft's IconsExtract. I'm still searching for a way to get MS Apps icons as I comment in What I'm working on above and my related question (link). I used IconsExtract directly on C Drive with subfolders (34.270 icons), but still didn't find the MS Apps icons. Any ideas?